# Mail Compose module stopped working in ios6

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, ios6

I have an app I built a while ago that uses the mail compose module and worked, however, once I upgraded to iOS6 it stopped working. This is my code in my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUi/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(IBAction)email;

@end
```

And this is my code for my .m:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

-(IBAction)telephone2 {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://01748826265"]];
}

-(IBAction)email {
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"info@pizzaprontorichmond.co.uk", nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"subject here"];
    [composer setMessageBody:@"message here" isHTML:NO];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error %@", [error description]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Does anyone know what's causing it to break?

Comment: A small tip change the 'tel:' schema to `tel:01748826265` without the the `//`. The iPhone 5 might not understand the `//` in the schema.

Comment: [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; remove this. maybe you are presenting and dismiss view instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding this statement.

```
composer.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to make this a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link :-

1. [Tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/compose-mail-application-in-iphone/)
2. [Example](http://snipplr.com/view/58761/)

After implementing this, please don't forget to set your account in `Settings` of your iPhone 5. Do add your mailing account. This will work and revert me if still face any issue.